# android.permission.READ_PROFILE in Android, what it does?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I have an Android app that requires `android.permission.READ_PROFILE` permission. In the documentation, it says "Allows an application to read the user's personal profile data.".

What are the profile data that is described here?

Answer (score 3):

Read the user profile from contact db.
More in the docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Profile.html